# Unable to locate package kubuntu-plasma5-desktop on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, repository, plasma

I am attempting to install `kubuntu-plasma5-desktop` on Kubuntu 14.04 amd64, following [these instructions](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Packages#Kubuntu)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:neon/kf5
sudo apt update
sudo apt install project-neon5-session project-neon5-utils project-neon5-konsole

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ci-train-ppa-service/landing-005
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubuntu-plasma5-desktop
```

Unable to locate package kubuntu-plasma5-desktop

How can I fix this error?

Comment: As far as I can see, the ppa:neon/kf5 no longer exists. I have looked at the ppa web site and it does not list kf5 or kf anything. Really odd as all the info on the web says to use this ppa for 14.04 dated up to November.

Answer (score 3):

### If you're using 14.04 (per the revised question)...

The `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next` PPA has no Utopic build. It's designed for the development version of Ubuntu and nothing else. Remove it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
```

By extension the `kubuntu-plasma5-desktop` package only lives in this PPA so you're not going to be able to install that yet.

Just use the Neon version in `ppa:neon/kf5` (which *only* works for Trusty). As the [blog announcement for all this](https://blogs.kde.org/2014/07/15/plasma-5-here-all-ready-eat-your-babies) states:

> Packages will be installed to /opt/project-neon5 and will **co-install** with your normal environment and installs to **14.04**

Once you've installed `project-neon5-session`, `project-neon5-utils` and `project-neon5-konsole` you should be able to choose Neon as a desktop session from the login screen.

### If you're using 14.10 (per the original question)...

The `neon/kf5` PPA is only intended for 14.04 Trusty. It doesn't have packages for Utopic. Remove it with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:neon/kf5
```

The `kubuntu-ppa/next` PPA should work on 14.10:

- It has [a Utopic build target](http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/next/ubuntu/dists/).
- Looking at [the Packages file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/next/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages), it does have a `kubuntu-plasma4-desktop` file.

If it's not working, check the output of `sudo apt-get update` (use `apt` if you like) and see what that's saying. Any warnings and errors about the second PPA are going to be relevant here.

Comment: I mistaked. My version is 14.04, not 14.10.

Comment: As of 5-Dec-2014, ppa:neon/kf5 doesn't work. `~ $> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:neon/kf5
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:neon/kf5'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`